# PayPal Live Webhooks suddenly stopped reaching our web server without any changes

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-subscriptions

We have had successful Live Webhook integration for subscription payments via PayPal for years. Suddenly Paypal stopped being able to reach our web server on live webhook events. There is nothing in apache2 or system logs anymore, no PayPal IPs, no requests to the webhook URL.

Sandbox webhooks work, we receive the requests and they appear green in Sandbox dashboard. Live Webhook simulator produces nothing, it also can't reach the webhook URL.

We do have Cloudflare but it has been working fine with PayPal for more than a year. We have not done any changes to the web site or to the PayPal configuration.

PayPal "support" has no clue what is happening, the guy who is obviously not a "product engineer" said he sees "error 500" in his "dashboard", which seems to be a placeholder error for various causes and not an actual 500 error since they do not reach our server from their live infrastructure at all in order to get any sort of error.
I was told their "product engineers" will look into the problem, it has been a week and no one bothers to reply to the ticket anymore.

We have tried adding a second webhook URL which is simply a test php page that logs every request to it, PayPal could not reach it, yet this caused many of the "pending" webhooks to turn green and "sent". However this has no sense since no requests reached our server from PayPal.

Has this happened to anyone? Does anybody have any idea what we could do while we wait the eternal wait for PayPal engineers to bother to reply to a high volume merchant?

Just to clarify, PayPal IP range and webhook URL are already added in cloudflare pagerule/firewall allow lists and on the firewall on our server. I repeat that there were no changes on the server or cloudflare or PayPal when this problem started occurring.

Comment: Try a different domain name for your listener

Comment: How would that help in resolving the issue on my domain?

Comment: It will tell you if that's the issue.

Comment: I did configure a second domain, that's not the issue, live webhooks arrive if "Resend" button is clicked on failed webhooks, but new webhook events still are not reaching the server.

Comment: we are having the same issue. I thought it was due to me using my own code instead of their provided solutions, but that was not the case. I have contacted them, and they have told me that their engineers are looking at it. It has been more than a week that I reported it.

Comment: Eventually webhooks started coming in on the alternative domain, so we are stuck with it. Worth noting that to this day PayPal failed to fix the issue and notifications are still not arriving via the main domain so we removed it altogether from webhook settings.